# uniformly equivalent Riemannian metrics and quasi-isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a compact Riemannian manifold $M$. We say two Riemannian metrics $g_1$ and $g_2$ are uniformly equivalent iff There exists a positive constant $C$ such that $C g_2 > g_1 > \frac{1}{C} g_2$. We say that they are quasi-isometric if for any $x, y$ on $M$ there are uniform constants $C$ such that $Cd_1(x, y) + C < d_2(x, y) \leq Cd_1(x, y) + C$, where $d_1$ is the distance with respect to $g_1$ and $d_2$ is the distance with respect to $d_2$.

My question is does uniform equivalence imply quasi-isometry. I guess this boils down to showing that you can control $d_1(x, y)$ with $d_2(x, y)$ assuming uniform equivalence. Given a curve $\gamma(t)$ connecting $x$ and $y$,
$$\operatorname{length}_{d_1} (\gamma(t))  = \int_{0}^{1} |\gamma'(t)|_{g_{1}} dt.$$ In local coordinates we have

$|\gamma'(t)|_{g_{1}} = \sum_{ij} g_{1, ij} \gamma_{i}'(t)\gamma_{j}'(t)$. Can this be controlled by $|\gamma'(t)|_{g_{2}}$? Seems not because there are crossed terms that do not have a sign. But we can compute in normal coordinates with respect to $g_1$ such that $g_2$ is diagonalized. Then the cross terms go away. Is that right?

Comment: I suggest, you write in detail what the inequality $C g_2 > g_1 > \frac{1}{C} g_2$ means. (And you do not need local coordinates, they will only confuse you.)

Comment: I also think of that inequality in terms of coordinates…

Comment: Then try to write in detail at least that. The standard definition is that $g_1\ge g_2$ if for each tangent vector $v$, $g_1(v,v)\ge g_2(v,v)$. What is your definition?

Comment: I see, from this definition it should be clear. My definition is simply $C g_{2, ij} > g_{1, ij}$ in terms of the components.

Comment: That's wrong definition, where did you find it?

Comment: May I ask why? That is just my interpretation.

Comment: For instance, because this condition depends on the choice of local coordinates. And also, the standard definition is different, so I suggest, you use it.